# If I have stored in Session an object that is a reference to an object in the Cache, does it take extra memory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

So, there's the HttpRuntime.Cache object and the Session one. Suppose I have the object Customers stored in the Cache, and I retrieve a Customer and store it in Session. Does the reference of Customer in Session take more memory? Or is it just the reference and all the memory is still in the Cache?